# How to set an OpenTelemetry span attribute for a FastAPI route?

Tags: fastapi, telemetry, open-telemetry

Adding a tag to a trace's span can be very useful to later analyse the tracing data and slice & dice it by the wanted tag.

After reading the [OpenTelemetry docs](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), I couldn't figure out a way to add a custom tag to a span.

Here is my sample FastAPI application, already instrumented with OpenTelemetry:

```py
"""main.py"""
from typing import Dict

import fastapi

from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import (
    ConsoleSpanExporter,
    SimpleExportSpanProcessor,
)
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.fastapi import FastAPIInstrumentor
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider


trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(SimpleExportSpanProcessor(ConsoleSpanExporter()))


app = fastapi.FastAPI()


@app.get("/user/{id}")
async def get_user(id: int) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Test endpoint."""
    return {"message": "hello user!"}


FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app)
```

You can run it with `uvicorn main:app --reload`

How can I add the user id to the span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the source code of the ASGI instrumentation's OpenTelemetryMiddleware ([here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/master/instrumentation/opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi/src/opentelemetry/instrumentation/asgi/__init__.py)), I realised you can simply get the current span, set the tag (or attribute), and the current span will be returned with all its attributes.

```py
@app.get("/user/{id}")
async def get_user(id: int) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Test endpoint."""
    # Instrument the user id as a span tag
    current_span = trace.get_current_span()
    if current_span:
        current_span.set_attribute("user_id", id)

    return {"message": "hello user!"}
```